# File Upload and cleanup with the Asp.Net Wizard control

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, file-upload

I'm updating an existing page that makes use of the asp.net wizard control.  I'm adding an optional step that will allow the user to upload a file.

I'm already past the first issue: I don't actually want to use the file until the wizard's finished button is selected, but I have to upload the file from the new step rather than the final step.  That's no big deal.  I just have an upload button on the page next to the control so you upload it in place.  At this point I save it to App_Data folder and change the appearance of the wizard step to show there's an uploaded file (with an option to change it).  There's also a custom validator control to make sure you finish that before moving on to the next step, but that's extra information.

The next issue is that I don't need or want these files around any more after I complete processing for the finish step, or if the user never gets that far.  I can clean up the file okay after the finish step, or if the user decides to change to a new file, so I've solved most of this as well.

My problem is that I want a better way to clean up files when the user abandons the wizard after passing the new step but before clicking 'Finish'.  I could do it in a batch app or on application start, but I'd rather keep the code all contained to the page with the wizard.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, delete any files with a creation date older than a reasonable threshold.  The threshold would depend on how long it takes the slowest possible user to complete the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the files, based on time created, in a convenient page load event.